# Style из ResourceDictionary в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

Создал проект следующего содержания:

[[image: Решение]]

Содержимое UserControl1.xaml:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StylesDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,391,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Height="26" Width="64" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
        <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test" x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <Test:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="327,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

StyleDictionary.xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

В таком случае все OK, но (ПРОБЛЕМА!) если переписать StyleDictionary.xaml, следующим образом (код взят из [Стили и шаблоны элемента Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates)), стиль не применяеся, кнопка в конструкторе и на этапе исполнения не видима

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                         EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                    Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                    Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                    Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                         StartPoint="0,0"
                         EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                        Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                        Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                        Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                        Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle">
                <!-- FocusVisual -->

                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2"
                         StrokeThickness="1"
                         Stroke="#60000000"
                         StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <!-- Button -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
              Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
              Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
              Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
              Value="23" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
              Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    x:Name="Border"
                    CornerRadius="2"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                    Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                    Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"
                                      To="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderDarkColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderLightColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                          (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefault"
                       Value="true">

                                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                        Property="BorderBrush">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                         EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush}"
                                        Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor}"
                                        Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Поможите люди добрые :)

PS: этот же код стиля размещённый в UserControl.Resources выполняет свою задачу.

Comment: Ну нажмите `ctrl+shift+b`...  Как только ресурсы скомпилируются все должно будет появиться.

Comment: Шутку оценил. Увы, если бы все было так просто

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения у уважаемого сообщества за дурацкий вопрос. С утра, на свежую голову, нашел несколько глупых ошибок в коде примера. Например переименовав стиль на свой лад не учел, что в дальнейшем коде есть ссылка на это имя. Удивительно, что этот ляп по разному проявляется в зависимости от места размещения кода в отдельном файле ResourceDictionary или ресурсах UserControl.
Кроме того в коде примера MS в строке:

```
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
```

ссылка на отсутствующий DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush.